# pick random lines from text files and send them through email

Tags: php, random

I am kind of new to this so I am hoping that you can give me a hand. The task is this:

I have 5 .txt files, each file contains 10 lines of text. I have to randomly select one line from each file and the these generated lines have to be sent through email to two email addresses.

Can you please provide some pointers ?

Thank you!

Comment: You could use iterate over your file list, get the contents `file()`, randomize it `shuffle`, then select an index..

Comment: Where exactly are you stuck?

Comment: Can you show the code you have written so far?

Comment: So far I can only get random lines from one file, i dont know how to get them form multiple files nor I don't know how to send the final result through email This is what I have so far: <?php
    $content = file("file.txt"); 
    $line = $content[rand(0, count($content) - 1)];
?>